# LAMP on archlinux

Tags: php, lamp, archlinux

There is a [nice tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-arch-linux) on how to set up lamp on archlinux.

After including the following lines in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`:

`# Use for PHP 5.x:
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script php
Include conf/extra/php5_module.conf`

I am getting the folowing error on `sudo systemctl restart httpd`:

`Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

If I comment the line `LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so`, I am getting no more the error but also php its not working.
Can anyone help?

It seems that [others](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/httpd-will-not-restart-after-installing-php-from-lamp-tutorials) encountered same issue.

The output of `systemctl status httpd.service` is:

`* httpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-12-20 11:12:51 EET; 5h 0min ago
  Process: 2550 ExecStop=/usr/bin/apachectl graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3049 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2390 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

The output of `apachectl configtest` is:

`[Mon Dec 21 00:46:28.514204 2015] [:crit] [pid 10566:tid 139771165026176] Apache
AH00013: Pre-configuration failed`

Comment: This is the output of systemctl status httpd.service:  * `httpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-12-20 11:12:51 EET; 5h 0min ago
  Process: 2550 ExecStop=/usr/bin/apachectl graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3049 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2390 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)`

Comment: I hoped there would be a more detailed error report. Guess not.

Comment: A few thoughts: What is the output of the `apachectl configtest` command? This should give you some idea about what is wrong with your configuration. Part of your problem may be that you are using a tutorial for Apache 2.2, judging by the date. Currently, Apache is at version 2.4 and the config files have a slightly different syntax, which is not downwards compatible.

A good starting point would be the [Apache page on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server), which is at least up to date with the 2.4 branch.

Comment: The output of apachectl configtest is: `[Mon Dec 21 00:46:28.514204 2015] [:crit] [pid 10566:tid 139771165026176] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
AH00013: Pre-configuration failed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the excellent [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP) this is a [known issue](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39218) and requires a small configuration change.

1. Comment the line about the `mpm_event_module`:

   ```
   #LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
   ```
2. Uncomment the line about `mpm_prefork_module`:

   ```
   LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
   ```

Next time, I suggest the Archlinux wiki as it is usually more up to date than blog posts.

Comment: Thanks p1xel. After following the 2 steps it is working.